# Jquery validation: error message not removed after field is valid

Tags: jquery, validation

I have a simple form with 2 required field and the error messages are placed in a sliding out div.
When you don't fill in any form the validation works fine and its displaying the error messages but when you fill in the field it keeps displaying the error messages.
i tried some solution give here but nothing is working and i don't know what is causing this. 
Here is my code:
HTML

```
<form id="login_form"  method="post">
<ul>
    <li>
  <label for="user">Gebruikersnaam</label>
  <input  type="text" name="user" id="user" />
  </li>
  <li>
  <label for="paswoord">Paswoord</label>
  <input  type="password" name="password" id="paswoord" />
  </li>


 <li>
  <input class="btn black" type="submit" value="Login" />
  <span id="password" ><a href="#">Wachtwoord vergeten?</a></span>
  </li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

Jquery

```
    var validator = $('#login_form').validate({     
     rules: {           
        user: {
            required: true},
        password: {
            required: true},                
        },
    onfocusout: true,

invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
 var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
  if (errors) {
    var message = errors == 0
      ? 'You missed 1 field. It has been highlighted'
      : 'You missed ' + errors + ' fields. They have been highlighted';
    $("div.error span").html(message);
   $("div.error").hide().slideDown('slow');
            setTimeout(function(){$("div.error").slideUp(); },10000);
  } else {
    $("div.error").hide();
  }
},

submitHandler: function(form){              
        $("div.ok").removeClass("error").hide().slideDown('slow');
        setTimeout(function(){$("div.ok").slideUp(); },10000);
        }
});
jQuery.validator.messages.required = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by creating extra variables:

```
invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
 var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
 var notifyDiv = $('#notify');
 var notifyMessage = $('#notify span');

  if (errors) {
    var message = errors == 0
      ? 'U bent 1 veld vergeten.Dit is aangeduid.':
       'U bent  ' + errors + ' velden vergeten. Deze zijn aangeduid.';
     notifyMessage.html(message);
     notifyDiv.addClass('error').removeClass('ok').hide().slideDown('slow');
            setTimeout(function(){notifyDiv.slideUp(); },10000);
  } else {
    $("div.error").hide();
  }
},

submitHandler: function(form){
    var notifyDiv = $('#notify');
    var notifyMessage = $('#notify span');
    var message = 'Formulier werd verstuurd.';
    notifyMessage.html(message);
    notifyDiv.addClass('ok').removeClass('error').hide().slideDown('slow');
    setTimeout(function(){notifyDiv.slideUp(); },10000);
}
```

}